# Haskell: convert unicode integer to actual unicode character

Tags: unicode, haskell, codepoint

Suppose that my Haskell function is given an input, which is supposed to be the number of a unicode code point. How can one convert this to the corresponding character?

Example:

123 to '{'.

Comment: I think { is decimal 123, not hex 0x0123.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `toEnum`. (`Char`s implement the `Enum` typeclass.)

Comment: Yep, or `chr` from `Data.Char`.